# how to clone a storage MBR drive to a GPT drive without affecting the rest?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mbr, clone, gpt

**current situation:**

i want to clone my D:\2TB HDD to a 10TB one and my E:\1 TB SSD to a 4 TB one.
both are for storage, got a truck load of stuff installed and configured as MBR but they need to be GPT partitioned. I simply want 1 volume per drive just like now. My Current C:\ drive is only 500GB so no point to make it GPT.
current motherboard model just in case: Asrock 970 Extreme 4

**so far i discovered:**

- MBR2GPT.EXE from Microsoft is not an option since they are both
  storage disks, MBR2GPT.EXE will only work for the master C:\ drive
  where Windows is installed.
- using Disk Management i discovered that i can only convert to GPT
  when no partitions and data are present (tested with an old 160gb hdd
  with sata to usb cable). which means converting MBR to GPT after
  cloning is not an option
- i don't see any UEFI mode thing in the BIOS but it *is* UEFI capable
  according to the motherboard manufacturer. i could test GPT as said
  above within Windows so it's fine i guess, otherwise it would be
  greyed out at all times.

**what i want to know:**

- would it work to hook up a new 4tb ssd using sata>usb cable, convert it to
  GPT using Disk Management, *then* clone it?
- is cloning better with software (clonezilla/acronic true image, etc.
  on bootable usb) or hardware? i cloned my C:\ recently with one of
  those Sharkoon boxes and it worked perfectly. however, i didn't bother with MBR-
  GPT since i went from 120GB > 500GB, and MBR tops out on 2TB
- does cloning itself affect the partition table?
- if the whole thing is succesful, can i keep using my bootable MBR C:
  drive along the 2 new storage GPT ones? as tested with the sata-usb
  way i guess yes but i want to be sure. all 3 drives will be hooked internally using sata
- any other tips, advice and knowledge i might need, share your experiences aswell if any

Comment: Motherboard firmware is either BIOS or UEFI and they're not the same thing - it's one or the other. Since you have UEFI, GPT should be used for the OS, as you likely have CSM [Legacy] Mode enabled in UEFI if using MBR, which degrades performance, serving no purpose today, and no purpose for Windows _(its sole purpose was to support non-EFI bootable Linux/BSD distros circa <2017, so CSM mode should always remain disabled)_. Specific to Windows, cloning HDDs is inefficient since NTFS has been the default filesystem since XP; instead, capture/apply a [WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend just booting a Linux USB stick, then running `gdisk` in there to convert all of your data drives to GPT *without* changing the way in which they're connected.

> My Current C:\ drive is only 500GB so no point to make it GPT

Using GPT is not entirely about the disk size. Among other things, it is usually a *requirement* for booting Windows in UEFI mode.

*(Though not necessarily for booting an OS in UEFI mode in general.)*

> i don't see any UEFI mode thing in the BIOS but it is UEFI capable according to the motherboard manufacturer. i could test GPT as said

The labels for this vary depending on manufacturer and the firmware's age. It might be "BIOS compatibility" or "legacy mode" or "CSM mode". Often, UEFI firmwares work in hybrid mode where the same boot menu offers both BIOS-mode and UEFI-mode options, so they might not necessarily have a global switch for that.

The boot mode, however, has nothing to do at all with your *data* disks. Those are read only by the OS – not by the firmware – and they can use any partitioning (or lack thereof) that the OS will support. All recent versions of Windows (post-XP) will be able to access GPT and MBR partitioned disks on any platform.

> using Disk Management i discovered that i can only convert to GPT
> when no partitions and data are present (tested with an old 160gb hdd with sata to usb cable). which means converting MBR to GPT after

There are other partitioning tools besides the Windows Disk Management applet which *can* convert a disk with partitions from MBR to GPT and back – the Linux `gdisk` being one example. This process doesn't do anything with your data; it just writes the same partition start/end information to the new table.

> would it work to hook up a new 4tb ssd using sata>usb cable, convert it to GPT using Disk Management, then clone it?

Probably not. If you clone the whole disk, this will just overwrite *everything* that's on the destination disk – including your freshly prepared GPT partition table. (It is stored on regular data sectors – specifically, sector 0 for the MBR and sectors 1-33 for the GPT.)

But also, be careful with SATA-to-USB adapters. **Some** of them emulate a different sector size for the disk – a '512b' disk connected through some such adapters will be seen as if it were a '4K' disk, that is, with virtual 4096-byte sectors. If you create a GPT partition table through such adapters, [it will not be recognized](https://superuser.com/a/1649993/1686) when the same disk is connected directly, nor the other way around.

(This is actually considered a "feature" – it's meant precisely to allow MBR usage on disks larger than 2 TiB, as the limit comes from the number of sectors, not of bytes.)

> is cloning better with software (clonezilla/acronic true image, etc. on bootable usb) or hardware? i cloned my C:\ recently with one of those Sharkoon boxes and it worked perfectly. however, i didn't bother with MBR- GPT since i went from 120GB > 500GB, and MBR tops out on 2TB

In theory, software might be more flexible – e.g. it might support cloning individual partitions from a MBR disk to an already-GPT disk; or if you are cloning a typical Windows system to a larger disk, it might support automatically growing the C:\ partition to the new size, and even shifting that pesky "Recovery partition" so that it ends up at the very end of the larger disk, instead of somewhere in the middle. (This is a theory. I haven't used cloning software which would do this.)

But when cloning the entire disk 1:1, it doesn't make any difference how you do it.

> does cloning itself affect the partition table?

As mentioned, it may or may not affect the partition table – it depends on how the cloning software actually works. If it clones the entire disk as a unit (like hardware cloning devices would), the output will have exactly the same partition table as the input, too. But if the software wants to be flexible (e.g. if it has options to clone only selected partitions but not others), then it is likely that it'll build a new partition table... though usually of the same type anyway.

Comment: thanks for the informative answers! some really good info there. I guess i can try to make ALL my disks (including my current C:\ )GPT without reinstalling / touching anything. is gparted the best for this? could i do this without even opening my pc? like boot with usb > make it all GPT > boot back into windows

Comment: Use gdisk (not gparted) for the data disks. Use MBR2GPT.EXE for the system disk, because it is more involved than the rest – it means switching to the EFI boot process, which means building an EFI System Partition and such (the tool will do that automatically, but it's still a bit more than just converting a data disk).

Comment: sounds great! i will keep that in mind for the data disks. also i discovered now that MBR2GPT.EXE sandly only supports 10. i'm on win7 64 bit now since 2014(yes i know, very long story, will move to 10 or 11 when building a new pc). i'll check if maybe some 3rd party software can help. but still. excellent to know for reference

Comment: It is possible to convert a system disk manually (doing the GPT conversion via gdisk, then reformatting the existing system partition to act as an "EFI system" partition and changing its GPT type accordingly, then running `bcdboot` from a Windows installation USB stick to rebuild its contents for UEFI)... but I'm not sure if bcdboot works equally well with Win7, and old PCs didn't always have reliable UEFI implementations either. If it came factory-set to 'legacy mode', or if it's an old WinVista/WinXP era machine, converting is probably not worth the trouble.